# Why Pictures are repeating on refreshing page?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to make image show permanent on refreshing.
The image should be constant. We can add images and text permanent and we can add more posts.

> A database called image_upload and create a table called images with fields:
>
> id - int(11)
>
> image - varchar(100)
>
> image_text - text

index.php

```
 <?php
  // Create database connection
 $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "image_upload");

      // Initialize message variable
      $msg = "";

    // If upload button is clicked ...
    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
        // Get image name
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        // Get text
        $image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['image_text']);

        // image file directory
    $target = "images/".basename($image);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, image_text) VALUES ('$image', '$image_text')";
        // execute query
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
            $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
        }else{
            $msg = "Failed to upload image";
        }
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Image Upload</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #content{
          width: 50%;
        margin: 20px auto;
        border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
       }
       form{
        width: 50%;
        margin: 20px auto;
       }
       form div{
        margin-top: 5px;
       }
       #img_div{
        width: 80%;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 15px auto;
        border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
       }
       #img_div:after{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        clear: both;
       }
       img{
        float: left;
        margin: 5px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 140px;
       }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content">
      <?php
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<div id='img_div'>";
            echo "<img src='images/".$row['image']."' >";
            echo "<p>".$row['image_text']."</p>";
        echo "</div>";
      }
    ?>
      <form method="POST" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
        <div>
          <input type="file" name="image">
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea 
            id="text" 
            cols="40" 
            rows="4" 
            name="image_text" 
            placeholder="Say something about this image..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Help me How to solve this problem. I have created database and uploading images and text. while refreshing page. The posts is repeating after and after.

Answer (score 0):

It now works. Tested. For over two hours I was baffled why the page could not redirect after successful upload. Undoing some indentations at the top of the page solved the problem.

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 // Create database connection
 $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "image_upload");

 if(isset($_POST['image_text'])){

    // Get text
    $image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['image_text']);     

 }

 if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    // Get image name
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tempath = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];     
 }

 // If upload button is clicked ...
 if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

     if(isset($image) && isset($tempath) && !empty($image)){

         $image = time()."_".$image;
         $image_folder = "images/";

         if(is_uploaded_file($tempath)){ 

             if(move_uploaded_file($tempath, $image_folder.$image)) {

                 $image_uploaded = true;    

                 }

            }
        }else{

            $msg = "Failed to upload image";

        }


     if(isset($image_uploaded) && ($image_uploaded == true)){

            $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, image_text) VALUES('$image', '$image_text')";
            // execute query
            mysqli_query($db, $sql);

            $sent = true;

            $_SESSION['sent'] = "Image uploaded successfully";

        }
    }


    if(isset($sent) && ($sent == true)){

            header("Location: index.php");
            exit();

    }


  $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Image Upload</title>

<style type="text/css">
    #content{
      width: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
   }
   form{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
   }
   form div{
    margin-top: 5px;
   }
   #img_div{
    width: 80%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
   }
   #img_div:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
   }
   img{
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 140px;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['sent'])){

     echo "<p style='color:#006400;font-weight:bold;'>" . $_SESSION['sent'] . "</p>";
     unset($_SESSION["sent"]);      

    }

    if(isset($msg)){

    echo "<p style='color:#ff0000;font-weight:bold;'>" . $msg . "</p>";

    }

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<div id='img_div'>";
        echo "<img src='images/".$row['image']."' >";
        echo "<p>".$row['image_text']."</p>";
        echo "</div>";
     }

  }else{

         echo "<h4>No data has been uploaded</h4>";

  }
?>
  <form method="POST" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
    <div>
      <input type="file" name="image">
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea 
        id="text" 
        cols="40" 
        rows="4" 
        name="image_text" 
        placeholder="Say something about this image..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the image and text inserted into the database?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the following will provide guidance ~ fully working but the paths used to store images is relevant to my laptop so you'll need to edit that portion slightly.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    $db  = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

    $msg='Failed to upload image';


    /* utility to find error if something goes wrong */
    function uploaderror( $error ){ 
        switch( $error ) { 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: return "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: return "No file was uploaded"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: return "Missing a temporary folder"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: return "Failed to write file to disk"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: return "File upload stopped by extension"; 
            default: return "Unknown upload error";
        }
    }



    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_FILES['image'] ) && isset( $_POST['image_text'] ) ){
        try{
            /* try to filter input of bad characters though using a prepared statement should help */
            $text=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'image_text', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

            /* get a reference to the uploaded FILE object*/
            $obj=(object)$_FILES['image'];

            $name=$obj->name;
            $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
            $size=$obj->size;
            $error=$obj->error;
            $type=$obj->type;


            /* proceed to save file and log to db */
            if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) && $error==UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){


                #$destination = 'images/' . $name;

                $root='c:/wwwroot';
                $path='/images/tmp/';
                $filepath = $path. $name;
                $destination=$root . $filepath;


                $status=move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $destination );

                if( $status ){  /* moved/saved the file OK */

                    /* create a prepared statement */
                    $sql='insert into `images` ( `image`, `image_text`) values (?,?)';
                    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

                    if( $stmt ){/* bind variables to placecholders ~ store path to image rather than just image name */
                        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $filepath, $text );
                        $status = $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->close();

                        $msg = $status ? 'Image uploaded successfully' : 'Failed to log image to database';
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Exception('unable to move file');
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception( sprintf( 'error: possible file upload attack - %s',uploaderror( $error ) ) );
            }
        }catch( Exception $e ){
            $msg = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


    /* fetch all image details from db */
    $sql='select `image`,`image_text` from `images`;';
    $result=$db->query( $sql );

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image Upload</title>
        <style>
            #content{
              width: 50%;
            margin: 20px auto;
            border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
           }
           form{
            width: 50%;
            margin: 20px auto;
           }
           form div{
            margin-top: 5px;
           }
           #img_div{
            width: 80%;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 15px auto;
            border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
           }
           #img_div:after{
            content: "";
            display: block;
            clear: both;
           }
           img{
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 140px;
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <?php

                $i=0;

                while( $row = $result->fetch_object() ) {
                    $i++;
                    /* an ID MUST be unique! */

                    echo "
                    <div class='img_div' id='img_div__$i'>
                        <img src='{$row->image}' />
                        <p>{$row->image_text}</p>
                    </div>";
                }
            ?>
            <form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                <input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='1000000' />
                <div>
                  <input type='file' name='image' />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <textarea 
                    id='text' 
                    cols='40' 
                    rows='4' 
                    name='image_text' 
                    placeholder='Say something about this image...'></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type='submit' name='upload'>POST</button>
                    <?php
                        if( !empty( $msg ) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) echo $msg;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```